# Recomendación de actualización con Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Actualmente tengo este ajax que lo guardo en una variable **json** Para luego crear contenido a partir de ella:

```
var json = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
     url:  "{%  url 'api-pedido' %}",
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: "json",
     async: false
}).responseText);
```

Y luego un ajax para enviar un delete al servidor :

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
   var pk = $(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
   url: "/pedido/"+pk+"/",
   headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
   type: 'DELETE',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   success: function(result) {
   $('.btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Atendiendo");
   location.reload();
  },
 });
});
```

**UPDATE** este es el html que genero (Cards de bootstrap)

```
   for (let pedidos of json) {
     let content = "<div class='col-xs-auto spaceCard'><div class='card'><h5 class='card-header'><span class='colorDnicos id'>Venta N°"+ pedidos.id +" -</span> " + pedidos.cliente +"</h5><div class='card-body'><h5 class='card-title'><span class='colorDnicos'>Descripción: </span>" + pedidos.descripcion + "</h5><div class='card-text'><ul>"

    for (let detalle of pedidos.detalleventa) {
      content += "<li>"+detalle.cantidad+ " " + detalle.producto +"</li>";
   }

      content += "</ul></div><button class='btn btn-primary btn-block' id="+pedidos.id+"><span class='fa fa-check'></span>Atendido</button></div</div></div>";

      $('.container').append(content);
   }
```

Todo funciona correctamente pero quisiera saber como actualizo mi lista del **GET** que me trae el ajax luego del success del DELETE  ya que actualmente con el `location.reload();` recargo la página pero quisiera que sea de una forma mas limpia, o sea que sin recargar se actualice. Me podrian dar recomendaciones?

Comment: ¿Cómo es tu lista? ¿Es una tabla html? ¿Podrías enseñarnos el código?

Comment: ¿Una llamada AJAX síncrona? Los navegadores deben estar mostrándote avisos (warnings) de que no deberías usar eso

Comment: Si con la variable json ya tienes los datos, podrías redibujar la tabla una vez finalizada la llamada ajax.

Comment: Si @Kiko_L actualice la pregunta con el codigo. y son cards de bootstap los que genero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes a la hora de la construir con el for los datos de la lista, puede annadirle un identificador al html, que sea unico para despues,en la fuction success de la llamada al delete, poder ocultar la fila seleccionandola mediante el identificador que le annadiste y con un efecto fadeOut, queda muy bueno asi. Saludos

```
     for (let pedidos of json) {
     let content = "<div class='col-xs-auto spaceCard' id="+ pedidos.id +"><div class='card'><h5 class='card-header'><span class='colorDnicos id'>Venta N°"+ pedidos.id +" -</span> " + pedidos.cliente +"</h5><div class='card-body'><h5 class='card-title'><span class='colorDnicos'>Descripción: </span>" + pedidos.descripcion + "</h5><div class='card-text'><ul>"

    for (let detalle of pedidos.detalleventa) {
      content += "<li>"+detalle.cantidad+ " " + detalle.producto +"</li>";
   }

      content += "</ul></div><button class='btn btn-primary btn-block' id="+pedidos.id+"><span class='fa fa-check'></span>Atendido</button></div</div></div>";

      $('.container').append(content);
   }
```

Y en la funcion success de la llamada al delete

```
 location.reload(); lo cambias por  $('#' + result.id).fadeOut("slow",function(){
    $('#' + result.id).remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que refactorizar tu código actual

Deberías poner dentro de una función el `request de ajax` que le asignas a la variable json y la de agregar el contenido de ese json en tu `container` para luego llamarla desde otras partes de tu código cuando las necesites.

te quedaría algo como

```
var json;

function getData() {
  json = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
       url:  "{%  url 'api-pedido' %}",
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: "json",
       async: false
  }).responseText);
}

function loadJson() {
  $('.container').empty();

  for (let pedidos of json) {
    let content = "<div class='col-xs-auto spaceCard'><div class='card'><h5 class='card-header'>" + pedidos.cliente +"</h5><div class='card-body'><h5 class='card-title'><span class='colorDnicos'>Descripción: </span>" + pedidos.descripcion + "</h5><div class='card-text'><ul>"

    for(let detalle of pedidos.detalleventa){
      content += "<li>"+detalle.cantidad+ " " + detalle.producto +"</li>";
    }

    content += "</ul></div><a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'><span class='fa fa-check'></span>Atendido</a></div</div></div>";

    $('.container').append(content);
  }
}
```

debes limpiar el contenido con la función `empty()` de jquery
y ahora puedes llamar a las dos funciones en `success` al eliminar el elemento

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
   var pk = $(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
     url: "/pedido/"+pk+"/",
     headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
     type: 'DELETE',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     success: function(result) {
     $('.btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Atendiendo");

     getData();
     loadJson();
    },
  });
});
```

no se si funciona porque lo modifique a mano, pero lo importante es que entiendas la idea

saludos